# How to write orderBy query with raw SQL in EfCore?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have EfCore query:

```
 return await _context.Rubrics
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(i => i.IsApproved == true)
                .Include(i => i.EdDraft)
                .Include(i => i.Rubric)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Title)
                .Where(i => i.EdDraft.AccountId == accountId)
                .OrderBy(i => i.Path)
                .ToListAsync();
```

i.Path is string like "1-5-3", "1-5-3-2", "9-18-12" and etc...
I have to order by char - the first character, for example order by "1-", "9-" and etc.

I don't want rewrite all query with raw [sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).
In Laravel I do:

```
orderBy(DB::raw(...sql))
```

but in EfCore I can't find a solution.

I know how I can rewrite on client side (.AsEnumerable), but I need write query on server side.

Query has to order by first character in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF core translates Substring method of string to SQL just fine but it requires 2 parameter overload. So if I understand your question correctly - "how to order the query just by first character" - use:

```
 return await _context.Rubrics
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(i => i.IsApproved == true)
                .Include(i => i.EdDraft)
                .Include(i => i.Rubric)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Title)
                .Where(i => i.EdDraft.AccountId == accountId)
                .OrderBy(i => i.Path.Substring(0,1))
                .ToListAsync();
```